# How do I implement a pure functional architecture for a project containing objects that do change over time with Scala and scalaz

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scalaz

I have a project where I'm implementing a vending machine. I have an object VendingMachine, which has another object inside it called CoinOp. I want the CoinOp object to accept coins of various values. The VendingMachine can ask the CoinOp to tell it how much money the user has entered. For that to really work, the CoinOp has to be able to change the amount of money it has inside it.

VendingMachine looks like this:

```
class VendingMachine {
    val coinOp = new CoinOp()
}
```

I want to do this in a functional way, which immediately removes this implementation of CoinOp as an option:

```
class CoinOp {
    var money = 0.0f

    def addCoins(amount: Float) = money += amount
}
```

Instead I need to do something like this:

```
case class CoinOp(money: Float) {
    def addCoins(amount: Float): CoinOp = CoinOp(money + amount)
}
```

I get that I can use scalaz to do something like this. The implementation in scalaz isn't really the focus of this question.

My question is this: Given that I can functionally update the amount of money the CoinOp has, how do I show VendingMachine that has changed?

Creating the new CoinOp object in addCoins is great and all, but it is a new object, and it doesn't mutate the object to which VendingMachine has a reference. Which is good persistence, all part of functional programming. But, I need the VendingMachine to use the object that addCoins() creates instead of the  one that is in the class definition. How do I do that?

The only thing I can think of is to make the coinOp object in VendingMachine a var, which I can then set in response to calls to CoinOp#addCoins. But that doesn't seem like a good solution to me.

Could someone please explain how something like would be set up?

Comment: Seems like you are looking for State Monad.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to do functional programming you stick as much as possible to methods without side effect and immutable structures, like you did with your

```
case class CoinOp(money: Float) {
  def addCoins(amount: Float): CoinOp = CoinOp(money + amount)
  def addCoins(amount: CoinOp): CoinOp = CoinOp(money + amount.money)
}
```

So that, as you said, when calling `addCoins` method you will get new `CoinOp` instance returned.

But the problem here is your task. Having vending machine implies that you have some state that you need to maintain. And state is, unfortunately, `var`.

So if you don't need thread safety, you simply create private variable of type `CoinOp` and when adding funds - you assign another instance of `CoinOp` to this var. This way you will have your `CoinOp` class immutable, but `VendingMachine` will have a state and will be mutable.

```
class VendingMachine{
  var funds: CoinOp = CoinOp(0)

  def addFunds(amount: CoinOp): CoinOp = {
    funds = funds.addCoins(amount.money)
    // or rather use addCoins(CoinOP):
    // funds = funds.addCoins(amount)
  }
}
```

If you want to have a synchronised access to your funds state - Scala way is Akka Actor, keeping your state inside itself

Comment: I feel like this doesn't solve the problem at all.  It doesn't remove the state, just moves it somewhere else.

Comment: As I understand that - state is nature of some problems. This is the reason why libraries like akka actors exist at all. So having state - is part of the VendingMachine nature. And you need to deal with it.

Comment: OP did not ask anything about managing state in a concurrent context, which is why you'd reach for Actors in the first place.